# How do I query for all Firebase AB experiments that a user has seen?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am working on an iOS app that uses the Firebase iOS SDK and I'm trying to figure out how to access all the Firebase AB experiments that a user has seen as well as the experiment variations that the user was bucketed into.

I looked through the documentation as well as the FirebaseABTesting.framework but I haven't been able to find a way to do so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to find a way to record this information yourself somehow based on the way you observe the user using your app.  You could also [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) that describes what you're trying to do.

Comment: What about today? :)